# AJAX. Como pegar com o PHP os dados enviados pelo "username" e "password" quando setado no ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Sei que tem outras formas de enviar e pegar dados Ajax-PHP, mas dando uma lida na documentação do jQuery-Ajax vi que tem a opção do username e password, onde pelo que entendi dá uma segurança ao enviar esse tipo de informação para o servidor(PHP). Talvez tenha entendido errado do real funcionamento, mas enfim...

Eu seto os valores pego pelo formulário no username e password no ajax, mas não sei como resgatá-los no PHP. Envio via POST, mas como não passo nenhuma key, não tenho a mínima ideia de como pegar no PHP.

Gostaria de um help e se possível uma explicação sobre a utilização do username e password no ajax, se realmente fornece mais segurança ao realizar a requisição, diferente de outras formas de enviar dados para o servidor.

jQuery-Ajax.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'dados.php',   

                // Passando o username vindo do formulário.
                username: $('#username').val(), 

                // Passando o password vindo do formulário.
                password: $('#password').val(), 

                success: (resp) =>{
                     // Em caso de sucesso...
                },
                error: (resp) =>{
                    // Em caso de erro...
                },

            });
```

PHP.

```
<?php

    // Como que pego os dados passados pelo username e password?
    // Já tentei utilizar o $_POST['username'] e $_POST['password'], mas não pega nada.
    $user = $_POST['??????????'];
    $pass = $_POST['??????????'];

    if ($user == "" || $pass == "") {
        echo "Nenhum campo pode ficar vazio.";
    } else {
        echo "Seu username: ".$user.", password: ".$pass;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

vamos "refatorar" seu código:

```
var strObjeto = JSON.stringify({
            username: $('#username').val(), 
            password: $('#password').val(), 
            });

            function salvaRegistroAdicional(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "dados.php",
                    data: strObjeto,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response) {
                            //trata a resposta
                            alert("Salvo com sucesso!");
                        }else{
                            alert(response.error);                    
                      }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert(error.message);
                    }
                });
            };
            salvaRegistroAdicional();
```

Dessa forma você vai fazer a requisição:

no seu form `dados.php`, você vai poder recuperar os dados desta forma

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```

você pode verificar o retorno na aba network do Devtools do navegador.

Comment: Opa! Então, eu consigo enviar via json, direto pelo data... até aí tudo ok. Como estava vendo um meio mais seguro de enviar tanto o login ou a senha para o servidor, vi na documentação o "username" e "password", aí pensei que estariam dando segurança ao enviar o login e a senha. Por isso tentei fazer a requisição com eles e não consegui, pois acredito que esteja faltando algo ou eles sirvam para outro propósito.
Mas o real motivo é saber como utilizar eles e se dão realmente mais segurança.